# "Carry on" vs. "go ahead"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, differences

I am confused about whether it is okay to say,

> "Ok, **carry on/go ahead** with your job then."

Any help on this simple issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: There's no real difference in the phrases; they both express the same status difference (master to servant) and the same directions (Continue.) and the same attitude (All is well.) and the same metaphor theme (Life Is A Journey, with servants). The only real difference is which part of the metaphor theme gets prominence: _carry on_ refers to bearing burdens, while _go ahead_ refers to scouting and preparation for arrival.

Comment: The only difference I can think of between the two is that *carry on* should only be used to indicate that a task should be **resumed** or **continued**, while *go ahead* can be used not only for those, but for a task's **commencement** as well.

Comment: @Hellion  This is usually true, but I'd add the possible exception in a military setting, where "carry on smartly" can be for sending someone away, either to begin or continue. Carry-On Smartly: (Normally followed by the word Shipmate, if your not a NUB!)  A navy tradition to be curt or kind in terms of sending someone away.  It's all in the tone of voice and delivery. http://www.nukeworker.com/forum/index.php?topic=26145.0

Answer (score 2):

As both [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140213/carry-on-vs-go-ahead#comment287768_140213) and [Hellion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140213/carry-on-vs-go-ahead#comment287774_140213) note, either option are acceptable. There are some subtle differences between the two. From Hellion:

> The only difference I can think of between the two is that *carry on* should only be used to indicate that a task should be **resumed** or **continued**, while *go ahead* can be used not only for those, but for a task's **commencement** as well.

Comment: I would add that **carry on** can be used as an encouragement, and doesn't necessarily connotate an authority's approval.  On the other hand, **go ahead** definitely implies that permission was needed from a superior.